# Is it possible to shade some package in only one package in sbt?

Tags: java, scala, jar, sbt, sbt-assembly

let's consider a following source code:

```scala
assemblyShadeRules in assembly ++= Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.common.**" -> "my_package.@1")
   .inAll
)
```

It renames `com.google.common` and change package names as well.  Additionally, thanks to `inAll` it rewrites all imports and another references in **all** classes in jar. It works fine. However, the question is:

Is it possible to rewrite only chosen references? I mean pointed by me using path to package?

Let's say something like:

```scala
assemblyShadeRules in assembly ++= Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.common.**" -> "my_package.@1")
   .inPath("org.apache.spark")
)
```

I would expect that **only** classes under `org.apache.spark` package will be rewritten (its references to `com.google.common`).

Comment: And so?what the issue?

Comment: Is it possible to gain such effect as I pointed? `inPath` does not exist. It was only example, please read carefully.

Comment: `ShadeRule.rename("org.apache.commons.io.**" -> "shadeio.@1").inLibrary("commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved using [`inLibrary`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/master/src/main/scala/sbtassembly/AssemblyPlugin.scala#L18) method. It's usage is:

```scala
assemblyShadeRules in assembly ++= Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.common.**" -> "my_package.@1") // it defines what/how to rewrite (belowe we define where to rewrite)
    .inLibrary("com.google.guava" % "guava" % "30.1-jre") // it rewrites references and packages names "com.google.common -> my_package.com.google.common")
    .inLibrary("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core" % "2.4.7") // it rewrites references (e.g. imports to guava from spark-core code)
)
```